# How to get the limited result from Django query when filtering with a list of IDs.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, orm

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut

Above is the link I am taking reference,

Following is my query which contains two values in a list with which I want to filter that data.

```
ans = Answer.objects.filter(question=1)
 ans.values('id')
```

which gives the output `<QuerySet [{'id': 2}, {'id': 42}]>`

and when I try to use it in the query below,

```
Comment.objects.filter(answer_id__in=ans.values('id'))[0:5]
```

it gives me out of just 5 elements. i.e., `<QuerySet [<Comment: 4>, <Comment: 5>, <Comment: 26>, <Comment: 27>, <Comment: 28>]>`

What I want to do is, I want my output which will give me 5 elements of each ID. (Not just total 5 elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

To get 5 records from each qs

```
ans = Answer.objects.filter(question=1).values_list('id', flat=True)
result = []

for a in ans:
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(answer_id=a)[:5]
    result += list(comments)
    
## use results
```

Comment: Great. thanks fot the answer. Don't we have any other way with which we can do it directly in query ?